# Integrals of sum. FInd upper and lower bounds

Tags: integration, discrete-mathematics, riemann-sum

Find the upper and lower bound using integrals.

$$\sum_{k=1}^n (k^2 - 3k)$$

Please explain I actually want to understand it

Comment: So, you are trying to bound this sum with an integral? Have you found functions that can be integrated which are bigger and smaller than this?

Comment: How do I find that ?

Comment: See also [Faulhaber's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula).

Answer (score 1):

A difficulty
with this question
is that it asked for
"the" upper and lower bounds.
There are *many*
upper and lower bounds
that could be used.

In general,
if $f(x)$ is increasing,
$\int_{k-1}^{k} f(x) dx
< f(k)
<\int_k^{k+1} f(x) dx
$,
with the inequalities
being reversed if
$f(x)$ is decreasing.

In your case
$f(x) = x^2-3x$
is decreasing at $x=1$
and increasing for
$x \ge 2$.
This can be handled by
separating out
the terms for $k=1$ and $2$,
writing
$\sum_{k=1}^n (k^2 - 3k)
= -2+\sum_{k=2}^n (k^2 - 3k)
= -2-2+\sum_{k=3}^n (k^2 - 3k)
$
and bounding the second or third sum,
the terms of which are increasing.

Comment: This makes sense, thanks

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by second or third sum?

Comment: Because $x^2-3x$ is increasing for $x > 3/2$, to apply both inequalities we need $x > 1+3/2 = 5/2$ or $k \ge 3$ for integer values. Therefore we can not use the terms for $k=1$ or $2$.

Comment: I don't exactly get your drift :(

Comment: The inequalities relating a value to integrals depend on their direction on whether the function is increasing or decreasing. The function $f(x) = x^2-3x$ is decreasing for $x < 3/2$ and increasing for $x > 3/2$. To use one of the inequalities, $f(x)$ has to be only increasing or only decreasing. Therefore, to use the inequalities for the increasing case, we have to remove the cases where the function is not increasing.

Comment: Okay, i understand that. So in other words , if we take k to be 3/2, the bound will be (3/2)-1 to (3/2) and (3/2) to (3/2)+1